# Codeigniter - Change in config item is not being preserved

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a scenario in which I want to save an object in the config array. I save via

```
$this->config->set_item('obj', $obj);
```

It works, I can retrieve its value via:

```
$this->config->item('obj');
```

But this values is not being preserved properly. When I go from one page to another, the value is lost. I can store the value in session, cookie or database, but I don't want to. Is there a way I can store the value in some global variable, change it often and the value is preserved as long as the application is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You can't.

You are storing the config item at runtime. The config item is available as long as the script is running. So when a page is finished loading , it means the script has finished its execution and all the runtime data are also gone.

In order to store it permanently , you must store it in session/database/filesystem.

You can use PHP's `serialize()` function.

Comment: Yep that is just what I wanted to confirm. Thanks.